# Call event using button c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to call **PaintEventArgs** when i press a button, my problem is i don't know how to call one without modify button event

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e /*<= PaintEventArgs*/)
    {
        func(e);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

Comment: A button's click event argument will not be paint related. You have a X/Y problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Since your Button Click event will not provide [PaintEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.painteventargs?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), you'll just have to construct the desired instance yourself.

Comment: Fiburt how? Still don't know how to call the paint event without doing it on PaintEventArgs

Comment: Tanveer just want to draw on click

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to draw and what exactly do you want to draw it on?

Comment: @HHopter Did you take a look at the examples in the linked documentation? It sounds like it exactly shows what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [Invalidate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-control-invalidate)
It will cause the control to be redrawn

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e /*<= PaintEventArgs*/)
    {
        //func(e); It will be called in the OnPaint method
        Invalidate();
    }
```

To use PaintEventArgs you need to override OnPaint method

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPaint(e);
   func(e);
}
```

To implement the OnPaint you need to create your own class that inherits the Button

```
public class BetterButton : Button{
   public BetterButton() 
   {}
   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
      base.OnPaint(e);      
      func(e);
   } 
}
```

Comment: And now the main problem, how do i use it in a button?

Comment: Create a class derived from Button and override the OnPaint method like in the answer

Comment: Still don't work, when the button is painted the function is painted.

Answer (score 0):

You ALWAYS do the drawing on the `Paint` event of the control you want to draw on. That might mean in the overridden `OnPaint` method or else in the `Paint` event handler. In order to cause thew `Paint` event to be raised, you call the `Invalidate` method of the appropriate control. You can call it with no arguments but, ideally, you would calculate the smallest area that has or might have changed and pass that as a `Rectangle` or the like.

EDIT:

Here is an example that will draw the last recorded time in the top-left of the form and update that time on each click of a `Button`:

```cs
private DateTime time;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    time = DateTime.Now;
    Invalidate();
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(time.ToString(), Font, Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
}
```

As you can see, all you need to do on the `Click` event is update the data and invalidate the form. All the drawing, including the `PaintEventArgs`, is taken care of in the `Paint` event handler.

Comment: Still don't explain how to call PaintEventArgs on button_Click(..) but how to call PaintEventArgs in the same time as PaintEvent

Comment: @HHopter, I didn't explain how to do that because it's not a thing. You're not calling the `OnPaint` method or `Paint` event handler directly so there's no reason for you to provide a `PaintEventArgs`. Just do what you've already been told and it will work. You call `Invalidate` on the control and it will raise its `Paint` event and provide its own `PaintEventArgs`.

Comment: @HHopter, see my edit for an example.